# I think I got scammed by sugar daddy

Tags: scams, sugar-daddy

I went into the sugar daddy Instagram accounts because I was in need of money. Then, I realized he was a scammer because he asked me to pay for some “fee” money. A lot of it. He kept sending me screenshots of how he is sending but I also needed to send this “fee” for it. Anyways, unfortunately, I did send a little bit before I realized it was a scam and blocked him. Also blocked the transactions.

I did not receive any payments from him, although he told me he sent the money but his “banker” needed to speak with me for me to receive any money. I did not say anything or did not receive any payment. Could he threaten me with anything after that?

I just never want to be in contact with these people and be done with this situation. I just want to make sure he can’t hold anything against me.

Comment: You should assume he is a scammer from the word "Sugar daddy". Nothing in this life is for free.

Comment: If your sugar daddy is too poor to take care of some odds and ends transfer fees then he's too poor to support a sugar baby.

Comment: Maybe also a good idea to look over what other information you may have shared with this person prior to breaking off contact.  Just in case you gave him anything he can use to steal your identity or break into other accounts.

Answer (score 17):

Assuming you haven't actually signed any sort of contract (which I'm willing to bet you haven't) and it was your own money that you sent him, then no, he can't hold anything against you.

HOWEVER, having read lots of questions on here from people in similar situations, it's also quite likely that he will try to threaten you with various things (eg he's going to report you to the bank, the police, the FBI etc). This is all baseless - he's a scammer and the last thing he wants is the authorities involved in his life - but it will probably seem scary. Just block him, delete any messages and move on.

The other thing that might happen is that you might get contacted by "lawyers" offering to "reclaim" the money you lost to a scammer and if you'll just pay $$ then they'll be able to release the reclaimed money to you etc. Needless to say, if this happens it is also bogus.

Unfortunately you will need to chalk this up to a lesson learned and hopefully it wasn't too expensive a lesson for you.

Comment: I wonder are there any legitimate sugar daddies / sugar mummies around at all? Or do we just not hear about it?

Comment: @gnasher729 Prostitution is real, but I think a legitimate online sugar daddy arrangement is so rare that it is essentially non-existent. It is all scammers, preying on young women.

Comment: @gnasher729: Yes, there are legitimate sugar daddy arrangements (and perhaps sugar mommies), but they all involve physical contact.  See the original meaning of a sugar daddy.  (I've read that there are web sites that facilitate such arrangements, but have no personal experience of them.)

Comment: @gnasher729 I have heard stories of some models from camgirl sites or OnlyFans who groom their most dedicated fans into sugar daddies. The scene calls that technique "girlfriending" (or "boyfriending", I would assume, for male models). But phase one of that plan does of course involve getting naked on the Internet.

Answer (score 16):

Here’s a basic principle that applies anywhere: if I want to send you money, I send it to you. If there are fees, I send you less money to pay for the fees. Anyone asking *you* to pay is a scam. Always.

When this lawyer contacts you offering to recover your money for a fee - if he were real, he’d recover your money and send it to you minus the fee. If the inland revenue sends you a $1,000 tax refund but first you must pay a $100 fee - the real inland revenue doesn’t charge you for sending you money, and if they did, they’d send you $900 instead of $1,000.

Anyone who charges money before they give you money is a scam. And anyone sending you a cheque and then wanting money is a scam.