# New job turned out to be scam to use received money to buy then sell bitcoin-how do i fix when money is gone?

Tags: scams, cryptocurrency

I accepted a remote secretary position recently, gave my bank information for direct deposit paychecks.

It went from he's supposed to mail secretary office supplies to me to asking me to buy bitcoin with some money that he had zeele to my account. I've never messed with bitcoin before, didn't understand. But I did what he said and with the money moved to my cashapp then bought bitcoin and put in a "wallet" with the information he gave me. Told him I don't understand and I'm very uncomfortable with this-he told me he'll call and explain in the evening.  Never called me.

So, next day out of the blue I received 2 payments in my zelle via into my bank account. I text him if he sent something because it was from some ladies name, not him. He immediately asked if I received and to buy bitcoin again, send him screenshots of everything.

At this point I knew for sure it's a scam, not a real secretary job. So I blocked him.

No clue what I needed to do,  was worried since he had my bank information maybe he'll hack into my account and mess everything up. This is my main bank account i use for the more important things i do (like ebay or bill payments.)

So moved to my cashapp, ...and now I've blocked over 10 numbers from California,  Nevada,  and Florida. Made new email because he was sending threatening emails from him then from "fbi complaint department."
I am seeking options on what I need to, had to close and make new Facebook/messenger. Closed my whatapp.

I don't want any problems, I don't have access to the money that was sent. I just want to fix this...and never get a remote secretary position ever again. I don't know if I will be in trouble and I can't just leave this as it is.

Comment: You might want to look at [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/142561/i-think-i-got-scammed-by-sugar-daddy?rq=1) or [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/161047/i-am-in-a-sugar-daddy-scam-and-he-is-threatening-me-because-i-want-out-what-do). This is the exact same scam, they're pretending to be whatever you want them to be (employer, sugar daddy, romantic prospect, whatever) for you to launder their ill gotten money.

Comment: Whenever someone sends you money and wants you to send money back, it is a scam. Keep whatever you have in your bank account (but be aware that it will most likely disappear soon), don't send anything to them. The "FBI complaint department" would arrest him if he contacted them, so that's not going to happen.

Comment: And call your bank what to do about your account. They should have no problem opening a new account for you and moving everything over.

Comment: I appreciate your advice